# Mustache templates are not displaying nested objects in Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, mustache

I'm using Rabl in my Rails project to output JSON from my controllers. I then use Mustache coupled with the 'stache' gem to generate the templates. However, the Mustache template is not getting the info I need from one of my JSON feeds, and I've tried every example/solution I could find.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "connectons":[
   {
     "connection":{
        "status":"accepted",
        "user":{
           "id":2,
           "first_name":"Joe",
           "last_name":"Black"
         }
      }
    },
    {
     "connection":{
        "status":"accepted",
        "user":{
           "id":2,
           "first_name":"Joe",
           "last_name":"Black"
         }
      }
    }
   ]
 }
```

This is my template:

```
<ul>
{{#connections}}
  <li>
    <p>{{status}}</p>
    {{#user}}
      <p>{{first_name}}</p>
    {{/user}}
  </li>
{{/connections}}
</ul>
```

But nothing from the `user` node shows up. Everything from the `connection` node shows up just fine. I've tried everything I know. Is my JSON bad? I also don't know if it is related to any of the gems I am using. I was wondering if someone could help me troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was an issue with Devise--I think. Rabl was building the JSON just fine, but for some reason I had to change things in my controller.

I had to change this:

```
def index
  @connections = current_user.connections
end
```

To:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @connections = @user.connections
end
```

I can now access the information in my mustache template with no issues. I don't know why it works this way, but if I find out why, I'll post the info.